# SRTM vs Google Earth Pro elevation data

Tags: dem, elevation, srtm, google-earth-pro

I am working on elevation data for an area in Sudan. Between Google Earth Pro and SRTM elevation data, which one is more reliable?

Answer (score 4):

Both are the same.

Google Earth uses the SRTM elevation data according to [this topic](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gec-data-discussions/VeIm-UiBy8U) on the Google Earth Help Forum:

> The global terrain dataset is 90M SRTM

It says the same thing on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Earth):

> Google Earth uses digital elevation model (DEM) data collected by NASA's Shuttle Radar Topography Mission (SRTM).

Comment: [1 arc-second (~30m) SRTM is now available worldwide.](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/SRTM1Arc) I don't know if Google is using it yet.

Comment: I suspect Google will be using the void-filled SRTM (SRTM Plus), rather than the original SRTM, although this is more an issue in mountainous areas. If OP uses the original, would need to fill any voids themselves.

Comment: I am finding some differences (1-2 meters) between the two datasets, I am almost sure the I did the georeferencing well

Comment: I am using the 30 arcsec database, non Void-filled